# Validar Campo Único Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Fala galera, estou tentando aprender Laravel e atualmente estou meio travado em uma coisa aparentemente simples, é o seguinte.

Criei um sisteminha bem simples com login e outras coisas, e estou tentando implementar a edição dos dados do usuario logado, fiz as validações e la defini que o email é unique.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'type' => 'required|max:1'
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'required' => 'O campo ":attribute" é obrigatório!',
        'numeric' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ser um número!',
        'min' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ter no mínimo :min caracteres!',
        'max' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ter no maximo :max caracteres!',
        'type.required' => 'O campo "tipo" é obrigatório!',
        'unique' => 'Este ":attribute" não se encontra disponivel no momento!'
    ];
}
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, a validação funciona corretamente, porém, quando eu tento atualizar o registro de algum usuário, por não ter alterado o email do mesmo é me retornado o erro, como posso fazer para que a validação unique do email abra uma exceção para o usuario daquele ID?

Aproveitando, queria saber de vocês se essa forma de fazer validação é indicada, correta, segura, eficiente e coisas do tipo, teriam outra forma para me recomendar fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução Galera, vou disponibilizar caso mais alguém tenha esse problema.

No meu caso, eu utilizo o Laravel 5.4 e valido minhas requisições com Form Request, por isso não dava certo como nos exemplos da documentação, mas foi só adaptar que funcionou direitinho. O codigo ficou da seguinte forma.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UsersRequest extends FormRequest
{    
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    //$user = User::find($this->user);
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(Auth::user()->id)],
        'type' => 'required|max:1'
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'required' => 'O campo ":attribute" é obrigatório!',
        'numeric' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ser um número!',
        'min' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ter no mínimo :min caracteres!',
        'max' => 'O campo ":attribute" deve ter no maximo :max caracteres!',
        'type.required' => 'O campo "tipo" é obrigatório!',
        'unique' => 'Este ":attribute" não se encontra disponivel no momento!'
    ];
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adiciona no seu HTML os valores que são retornados pelo banco.

**Ex**: se estou editando o campo e-mail que no banco esta com valor **aaa@xxx.com**, no meu HTML o campo deve vir com **value=aaa@xxx.com**.

Assim, quando enviar um POST com os dados do form, mesmo que nao tenha editado nenhum campo o objeto vai para o servidor com os dados.

Comment: Mas eu faço isso, value="{{Auth::user()->email}}"> o problema é que o email que esta no usuario teoricamente não pode ser salvo no banco porque já existe, o que eu quero é fazer uma exceção para um determinado ID

Comment: Entendi, bom que conseguiu arrumar :)